# Consider strings of length 9 that satisfy the following conditions :

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, proof-explanation, combinations

Consider strings of length 9 that satisfy the following conditions:
(i) The string contains four digits chosen from the set ${2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}$.
(ii) The string contains all five letters $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, such that the first occurrence of letters (i.e. the leftmost letter) must be $A$, and the last occurrence of letters (i.e. the rightmost letter) must be $E$.
For example, $BCDAE2345$ doesn't satisfy the conditions since $A$ isn't the leftmost letter.

Solution:

> Choose 4 digits: $\binom{6}{4}$
> Choose location for 5 letters: $\binom{9}{5}$
> Choose relative arrangement of $B,C,D$: $P(3,3)$
> Choose relative arrangement of digits: $P(4,4)$
> Thus, the answer would be: $\binom{6}{4} \binom{9}{5} \cdot P(3,3) \cdot P(4,4) = 272160$

---

What I don't understand:

> To find the number of ways to put 4 digits in the string, why didn't we first find all the ways to pick 4 elements of the set which is $\binom{6}{4}$, then count the ways to put these 4 digits in the 9 letter string, so $\binom{9}{5}$. Then we count all the locations to put 5 letters in the string. so $C(9,5)$. Then we permute around the 4 numbers to find all arrangements. so $P(4,4)$. Then we fix A in the left and E and the right, so we need to permute 3 letters in the 3 possible places. so $P(3,3)$ which clearly gives me the wrong number of ways and I don't understand why. Honestly, I don't understand their solution very much and I don't understand why choosing location for 5 letters in a string is a combination. like how is that the same thing as calculating the number of 5 letter subset from a 9 element set. Please can someone give me a good intuition for why my solution doesn't work and theirs d

Comment: "Then we count all the locations to put 5 letters in the string. so $C(9,5)$". That is your mistake. Once you have chosen the locations of the digits, the locations of the letters is forced to be whatever is left over. If you remove that factor of $C(9,5)$, your solution is exactly the same as theirs.

Comment: @Mike Earnest Thank you i understand but can you answer this question please : I don't understand why choosing location for 5 letters in a string is a combination. like how is that the same thing as calculating the number of 5 letter subset from a 9 element set

Comment: There are $9$ locations. You need to choose $5$ of them. Hence, $C(9,5)$. For example, suppose you wanted to place letters in the first space, the third space, the fourth space, the seventh space, and the eighth space. That corresponds to the unordered selection of $\{1,3,4,7,8\}$, which is one of the combinations counted by $C(9,5)$, or $\binom 95$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Then we count all the locations to put 5 letters in the string. so C(9,5)".

That is your mistake. Once you have chosen the locations of the digits, the locations of the letters is forced to be whatever is left over. If you remove that factor of C(9,5), your solution is exactly the same as theirs.

> I don't understand why choosing location for 5 letters in a string is a combination. like how is that the same thing as calculating the number of 5 letter subset from a 9 element set.

There are $9$ locations. You need to choose $5$ of them. Hence, $C(9,5)$. You can think of the underlying set as being $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, where each number corresponds to a location in the string, and you need to select five of those locations. The order of the selection does not matter, since they already come with a left-to-right order.

For example, suppose you wanted to place letters in the first space, the third space, the fourth space, the seventh space, and the eighth space. That corresponds to the unordered selection of $\{1,3,4,7,8\}$, which is one of the combinations counted by $C(9,5)$, or $\binom 95$.